# Working around existing MutationObserver to insert DOM elements with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, mutation-observers

I wrote a Tampermonkey script to inject some DOM elements into a site I use for work, to make navigation easier. It no longer works because the vendor has introduced a MutationObserver presumably to stop people like me from doing this. Why, I don't know. I'm not doing anything nefarious.

I know this is what's happening because I can see my DOM elements briefly appearing and then disappearing. They aren't in the DOM tree any more and the site's JS contains code for MutationObservers:

```
// this is a property of a large object
value: function() {
  var e = this
  if (this._options.shouldContainFocus) {
    this._observer = new MutationObserver(this.handleDOMMutation)
    for (var t = this._contextElement; t && 1 === t.nodeType && "BODY" !== t.tagName;) {
      var n = t.parentElement
      if (n) {
        this._parents.push(n)
        this.muteNode(n)
        Array.prototype.slice.call(n.childNodes).forEach(function(t) {
          e.hideNode(t)
        })
      }
      t = t.parentNode
    }
  }
}

// this is what is called by the MutationObserver
this.handleDOMMutation = function(e) {
  e.forEach(function(e) {
    Array.from(e.addedNodes).forEach(function(e) {
      n.hideNode(e)
    })
    e.removedNodes.forEach(function(e) {
      var t = n._nodes.indexOf(e)
      t >= 0 && n._nodes.splice(t, 1)
    })
  })
}
```

So my question is... how can I get around this, if at all? All I can think of is to access some global list of MutationObservers but that doesn't appear to exist from what I can read (I hadn't heard of this API until today). The observer variable is not one I can access via `unsafeWindow` so I can't call the `disconnect` method. I've read the documentation on MutationObservers but can't find anything to help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: `and the site's JS contains code for MutationObservers.` Can you post this code? If the problem can be reproduced, there's a chance of being able to come up with a solution to it. (without the code, it'd be guessing in the dark)

Comment: You might be able to load a script before all others on the site (should be one of the tampermonkey settings, eg run-at document-start). If so you could overwrite MutationObserver with one of your own

Comment: I've added the code snippet. It's part of 94,000 lines of obfuscated code.

Patrick, that's a good idea. But wouldn't mine simply run independently of the other one? Ideally I would want to `disconnect` the vendor's one, but I can't figure out how to access it.

Comment: I don't mean make your own instance, ie `new MutationObserver()`. I mean overwrite it like `MutationObserver = function(){}` this way when their `new MutationObserver()` is called it would just return an empty instance that does nothing.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and the console shows the error `this._observer.observe is not a function` indicating it works. I'm using `@run-at document-start` in Tampermonkey so that `unsafeWindow.MutationObserver = function() {}` is run ASAP. But my DOM elements are still being removed! I'm assuming the vendor has a fallback option for browsers where MutationObserver is unavailable. What might that be? The script is enormous and I don't know what I'd look for.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, here's a possible way to overwrite `window.MutationObserver` before the document loads. Because `MutationObserver` gets called as a constructor, in order for the site's scripts not to throw errors, make sure to let your monkeypatched `MutationObserver` be callable as a constructor. Then, since the instantiated object can have methods called on it (like `observe` and `disconnect`), you might return a `Proxy` which, when a property is accessed (like `observer`), returns a function that is callable, but doesn't do anything. For example:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
window.MutationObserver = function() {
  return new Proxy({}, { get: () => () => null })
};

new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('saw a mutation');
}).observe(div, { childList: true });
div.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'bar';
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

If the initial reassignment of `window.MutationObserver` occurs before the site's scripts run, then calls to `new MutationObserver` will return observers that don't do anything. (As you can see in the above code, if you remove the reassignment of `window.MutationObserver`, you will see `'saw a mutation'` logged, whereas after the monkeypatching, nothing is logged.)

So, translating this to a userscript, paste in the `window.MutationObserver` reassignment, and make sure that the userscript runs at `document-start`, so that the script runs before the site's built-in scripts run. If you also wish to use `MutationObserver` in your own code, save a reference to `window.MutationObserver` before you reassign it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @match        https://somewhere
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

const oldMutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
window.MutationObserver = function() {
  return new Proxy({}, { get: () => () => null })
};
```

If the site you're on depends on `MutationObserver` properties and functions to return sensible values (like `takeRecords()`), then rather than returning a `Proxy` that does nothing, you might return a Proxy that gives access to an actual instantiation of a `MutationObserver` that, when `observe` is called on it, observes a *different* element (one which is never mutated):

```js
// Userscript code:

const oldMutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
const elementThatIsNeverMutated = document.createElement('div');
window.MutationObserver = function(callback) { // callback should never be called
  const observer = new oldMutationObserver(callback);
  return new Proxy(observer, { get: (obj, prop) => {
    if (prop === 'observe') return (targetNode, config) => {
      obj.observe.call(obj, elementThatIsNeverMutated, config);
    };
    const val = obj[prop];
    return typeof val === 'function' ? val.bind(obj) : val;
  }})
};

// Example of site's built-in code:

const div = document.querySelector('div');
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('saw a mutation');
});
observer.observe(div, { childList: true });
div.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'bar';
const arr = observer.takeRecords();
arr.forEach(() => console.log('some item in array'));
```

```html
<div>foo</div>
```

Comment: That is very kind of you to provide that code. Unfortunately I can't get it to work, the DOM elements I'm injecting in are still being removed even though I can tell MutationObserver has been replaced (see comment reply to Patrick Evans).

Comment: You need to replace `window` with `unsafeWindow` or run your userscript unsandboxed (i.e. inside the page context) by declaring `@grant none` in the header. Using the first method in FF also needs exportFunction AFAIK, look for examples.

Comment: As you can see in the comment I wrote in reply to Patrick, I am already using `unsafeWindow` -- that's how I can tell `MutationObserver` has been replaced by a dud function.